# Can't debug JS in Visual Studio: validating breakpoint location

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, debugging

After installing the latest VS 2017 (15.9.0) I can no longer debug JavaScript.  I keep getting a dialog that says: "validating breakpoint location:".  It's slow to validate, but mostly it hangs.

Anyone know how to fix this?

**Edit:**
Well my solution to this problem was to rebuild the project completely.  It took a while, but it does seem to fix this problem...for now...

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue and was able to fix it by removing the .suo file for the project and letting VS 2017 rebuild it.  My theory is VS was holding on to phantom breakpoints that could not be deleted from the IDE.

Comment: Deleted the .suo, but still got the error... Thanks for getting back to me though!

Comment: That is unfortunate, sorry it didn't work for you.  It is a very annoying bug and makes VS totally unusable for JavaScript.  I assume that you also exited VS and restarted it.  My steps were exit VS, delete the .suo file, restart VS.

Comment: Rechecked just in case. Same error. Just upgraded to VS 15.9.5; same problem, but I can cancel the dialog now.

Comment: I think I finally have a solid answer on this one.  Open your project in Visual Studio and then check task manager to see if you have a node.js server-side process using a lot of memory and cpu.  I was dealing with this problem and found that if I removed one of my projects both the high cpu/memory usage and the "validating breakpoint location" message both went away.  When I added the project back into the solution the problem returned.

Comment: just rebuilt the entire project. Seems to fix the issue.